# The category $\text{add}M$ for a module $M$

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and consider the category $\text{mod}A$ of finitely generated left $A$-modules. If $M$ is in $\text{mod}A$, then $\text{add}M$ denotes the full subcategory of $\text{mod}A$ whose objects are direct summands of finite direct sums of copies of $M$. I read that $\text{add}M$ is the smallest additive full subcategory of $\text{mod}A$ containing $M$, but I don't understand why.

It appears to me that the smallest additive full subcategory of $\text{mod}A$ containing $M$ should consist of the trivial module $0$ and finite direct sums of copies of $M$ (and all homomorphisms between these modules). Why do we need to take also their direct summands?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: I read it in the book Elements of the Representation Theory
of Associative Algebras, volume 1, in page 184.

Comment: This looks like the smallest [idempotent complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karoubi_envelope) additive full subcategory of $\mathrm{mod} A$ containing $M$.

Comment: Small remark: in your description of the additive subcat. gen. by $M$, you don't have to mention the trivial module as a special case. It is just an empty direct sum, i.e. when the index set is empty.